# Dot product and matrix transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

In Least squares optimization,
I have $A=\begin{pmatrix}
     1 & t_1 & t_1^2 & \cdots & t_1^k \\
     1 & t_2 & t_2^2 & \cdots & t_2^k \\
     \vdots  & \vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
     1 & t_n & t_n^2 & \cdots & t_n^k    
     \end{pmatrix}$
and b=\begin{pmatrix}
        s_1 \\
        s_2  \\
        \vdots\\
s_n\\
        \end{pmatrix}  c=b=\begin{pmatrix}
        x_0 \\
        x_1  \\
        \vdots\\
x_n\\
        \end{pmatrix}

And $f(x_0,x_1,...,x_n)=\left\lVert b-Ax\right\rVert ^2=(b-Ax).(b-Ax)=b.b-2b.Ax+Ax.Ax$.
I understand up to this but I don't understand in the next step how they change $b.Ax$ to $A^Tb.x$ and $Ax.Ax$ to $x.A^TAx$ .
That is I don't understand the step $b.b-2A^Tb.x+x.A^TAx$
Is there a rule on this dot products and  matrix transpose?

Comment: It's enough to note that for any two vectors, $x.y = x^Ty$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Then shouldn't $b.Ax$ be $b^TAx$

Comment: Right, and that's the same as $(A^Tb)^Tx$